# Calling an object method using JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

How can I access to some object methods using JSTL?

Let's suppose that my object is an instance of a Person class, and I have `getName()` method which I want to call inside a JSP page using JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the following syntax:

```
${person.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to display name is `<c:out value="${person.name}"/>`